# how to fix packet mismatching error of dotnet core web api and test api that I refereed with main web api [jenkins]?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget-package

I have created dotnetcore webapi along with dotnetcore test unit. I'm using Jenkins pipeline to automate the process but I'm getting error while restoring the packages as shown below.

```
Started by user admin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Checkout)
[Pipeline] git
 > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/myrepository/dotnetcoreapp # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/repository/dotnetcoreapp
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/repository/dotnetcoreapp +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision e425bdd515356da06b5490fd8e8df4e78b427752 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f e425bdd515356da06b5490fd8e8df4e78b427752
 > git.exe branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git.exe branch -D master # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -b master e425bdd515356da06b5490fd8e8df4e78b427752
Commit message: "'hhkhkhk'"
 > git.exe rev-list --no-walk cd7d9a6c945b239f6b724a5a3339e051a3efda88 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Restore PACKAGES)
[Pipeline] bat
[jenkins Pipeline] Running batch script

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline>dotnet restore  
  Restoring packages for C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj...
  Restoring packages for C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj...
  Installing Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.6.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.6.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.6.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
  Generating MSBuild file C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\obj\mathcalci.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Restore completed in 20.09 sec for C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj.
  Installing System.Collections.Specialized 4.0.1.
  Installing System.ComponentModel 4.0.1.
  Installing System.ComponentModel.Primitives 4.1.0.
  Installing System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter 4.1.0.
  Installing System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync 4.0.11.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener 4.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.TestPlatform.ObjectModel 15.8.0.
  Installing xunit.extensibility.core 2.3.1.
  Installing xunit.extensibility.execution 2.3.1.
  Installing Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHost 15.8.0.
  Installing Microsoft.CodeCoverage 15.8.0.
  Installing xunit.core 2.3.1.
  Installing xunit.analyzers 0.7.0.
  Installing xunit.assert 2.3.1.
  Installing Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 15.8.0.
  Installing xunit 2.3.1.
  Installing xunit.runner.visualstudio 2.3.1.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
  Generating MSBuild file C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\obj\mathcalcitest.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Restore completed in 33.44 sec for C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj.
[Pipeline] echo
packages are restored
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Clean)
[Pipeline] bat
[jenkins Pipeline] Running batch script

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline>dotnet clean 
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.8.169+g1ccb72aefa for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 10/19/2018 12:56:49 AM.
     1>Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln" on node 1 (Clean target(s)).
     1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
         Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
     1>Done Building Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln" (Clean target(s)).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.15
[Pipeline] echo
clean is done
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] bat
[jenkins Pipeline] Running batch script

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline>dotnet build --configuration Release 
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.8.169+g1ccb72aefa for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
  Restore completed in 77.74 ms for C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj.
  Restore completed in 77.74 ms for C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
  mathcalci -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\mathcalci.dll
  mathcalcitest -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\mathcalcitest.dll

Build succeeded.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
    16 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:07.89
[Pipeline] echo
build is done
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Pack)
[Pipeline] bat
[jenkins Pipeline] Running batch script

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline>dotnet pack --no-build --output nupkgs 
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.8.169+g1ccb72aefa for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

[Pipeline] echo
nupkgs package is created
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Publish)
[Pipeline] bat
[jenkins Pipeline] Running batch script

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline>dotnet publish . -r win-arm 
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.8.169+g1ccb72aefa for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restoring packages for C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj...
  Restoring packages for C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj...
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
  Generating MSBuild file C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\obj\mathcalci.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Generating MSBuild file C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\obj\mathcalci.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
  Restore completed in 3.3 sec for C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci\mathcalci.csproj.
  Installing runtime.win-arm.Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetAppHost 2.1.0.
  Installing runtime.win-arm.Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostResolver 2.1.0.
  Installing runtime.win-arm.Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostPolicy 2.1.0.
  Installing runtime.win-arm.Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.NETCore.App from 2.1.5 to 2.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : error NU1605:  mathcalcitest -> mathcalci -> Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.1.5)  [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : error NU1605:  mathcalcitest -> Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.1.0) [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
  Restore failed in 39.52 sec for C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (testing)
Stage "testing" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Publish to git)
Stage "Publish to git" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

so how can i fix the nuget package mismatching error ? I searched for similar error solution but nothing didn't worked out to me.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalcitest\mathcalcitest.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.NETCore.App from 2.1.5 to 2.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins Pipeline\mathcalci.sln]
```

indicates, that you are using an older package. This downgrade usually failes because other libraries and packages try to refer to the newer versions. 
Where is your configuration of what package version you use? 
Have you set a version for the Microsoft.NETCore.App Package in a hardcoded way?